# Firebase phone auth not sending the OTP in subsequent tries

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

*I could find similar questions to this have been asked before on StackOverflow but couldn't find a solution so here goes.*

---

I use Flutter phone auth in a Flutter app. Below is the code I'm using to request the OTP.

```
Future<Either<FirebaseAuthException, MobileAuthStatus>> onSubmitPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, {int? forceResendingToken}) async {
    Completer<Either<FirebaseAuthException, MobileAuthStatus>> completer = Completer<Either<FirebaseAuthException, MobileAuthStatus>>();

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: Durations.otpTimeoutInSec,
        forceResendingToken: forceResendingToken,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
          completer.complete(Right(MobileAuthStatus.completed(credential)));
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException authException) {
          completer.complete(Left(authException));
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
          completer.complete(
              Right(MobileAuthStatus.codeSent(verificationId, resendToken)));
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          if (!completer.isCompleted) {
            completer
                .complete(Right(MobileAuthStatus.otpTimeout(verificationId)));
          }
        });

    return completer.future;
  }
```

This code works. However the problem arises if a user logs in and logs out shortly after and tries to log back in right away. I don't receive the OTP.

```
Future<Either<FirebaseAuthException, User?>> onLogout() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    return const Right(null);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (authException) {
    return Left(authException);
  }
}
```

According to Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#codesent), this is expected behavior.

> By default, Firebase will not re-send a new SMS message if it has been
> recently sent. You can however override this behavior by re-calling
> the verifyPhoneNumber method with the resend token to the
> forceResendingToken argument. If successful, the SMS message will be
> resent.

The problem is, when the user logs out by calling the `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` invalidates the resend token as well. So I'm unable to request the OTP again.

How do I get around this constraint?